# Accessing an object twice in string

Tags: php

I've noticed this in PHP and MySQL when I've been trying to put some object values in my query. I did some google searching for "Accessing object property twice" and "-> PHP twice", but couldn't find much results. I think it's the way PHP processes strings and wanted a bit more information. This is my question:

```
<?php
class Object {
    public function __construct() {
        $this->a = new A();
        echo "This x is '$this->a->x'";
    }
}

class A {
    public function __construct() {
        $this->x = 1;
    }
}

$object = new Object();
?>
```

The above code will raise an error: `E_RECOVERABLE_ERROR : type 4096 -- Object of class A could not be converted to string -- at line 5`

However, if we give it a temporary variable like this:

```
<?php
class Object {
    public function __construct() {
        $this->a = new A();
        $x = $this->a->x;
        echo "This x is '$x'";
    }
}

class A {
    public function __construct() {
        $this->x = 1;
    }
}

$object = new Object();
?>
```

Then it works completely fine, or if we concatenate it, it also works fine

```
<?php
class Object {
    public function __construct() {
        $this->a = new A();
        echo "This x is '" . $this->a->x . "'";
    }
}
?>
```

Double quoted PHP strings are supposed to be able to recognize variables prefixed with `$` and automtically substitute them. This also works fine if we're only accessing the object property once (`->` single). I think the PHP double-quoted string stop processing after a single `->` thus the reason for th error:

`E_RECOVERABLE_ERROR : type 4096 -- Object of class A could not be converted to string -- at line 5`

Which makes sense if it is only being accessed once (since `$this->a` is still an object). I'm not entirely convinced and could not find much information on this in PHP, so I was wondering if anyone could elaborate or detail me more on this and why it happens?

Comment: I can duplicate the issue, but I didn't even know you _could_ use an object property in that way without putting in it curly braces like `echo "This x is '{$this->a->x}'";`. The only time I leave out the curly braces is when outputting a simple, monolithical variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct. PHP only takes `$this->a` as variable. You can see this also in the [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing):

> Similarly, an array index or an object property can be parsed. With array indices, the **closing square bracket (]) marks the end of the index**. The **same rules apply to object properties** as to simple variables.

This means in a double quoted string:

```
$arr[0][1] = "X"; 
echo "$arr[0][1]";  //Same as echo $arr[0] . "[1]";

$o = (object)["a" => (object)["b" => "X"]];
echo "$o->a->b";    //Same as echo $o->a "->b";
```

So to solve this you have to use complex curly syntax, e.g.

```
echo "{$o->a->b}";
      ↑See here↑
```

With this you can explicit define what the variable is and what normal string is.